# printing with the penny value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have these value stored in a decimal 10,2 field

```
1052730
956700
```

How do i print this using php so that the value is like

```
$10,527.30
$9,567.00
```

basically i am trying to avoid the value as

```
$1,052,730 <--- this i dont want
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the

```
 money_format($format, $value)
```

function in php. The details of the formatting is given [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: Good, except that the number is *100 (meaning `$value = 1052730` really stands for `10527.30`)...

Comment: Just be aware that money_format() is not cross-platform and it depends on the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that `1052730` is really `10527.30` as alluded to in your question:

```
$number = 1052730;
$decimals = $number % 100;  //30 in this case
$digits = floor($number / 100);
$paddedDecimals = str_pad($digits, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$out = '$' . number_format($digits, 0).'.'.$paddedDecimals;
echo $out; // $10,527.30
```

There are no floating point calculations used for the decimal part, so there's no need to worry about precision issues (although at this precision it would likely be hard to get a float error in there)...

Answer (score 1):

Just divide by 100:

```
<?php

echo number_format(1052730/100, 2, '.', ',') . PHP_EOL;
echo number_format(956700/100, 2, '.', ',') . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
printf ("$%01.2f", ($input / 100));
```